# How to generate package level logs in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, hikaricp, server.xml

We are using Hikari connection pool for database connection management in our application. We have configured Hikari CP as a resource in tomcat server.xml. Now due to some issue with HIKARI we require DEBUG level logs generated from HIKARI library. I tried configuring package level logger in conf\log4j.properties, but I am unable to see logs from HIKARI library. Is there any different configuration for logging from libraries used as resource in tomcat server.xml?

Below lines are added in log4j.properties file in conf directory.

```
log4j.logger.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG,CONSOLE
log4j.additivity.com.zaxxer.hikari=true
```

Hikari resource configuration in server.xml.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/abc" auth="Container"
 factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 minimumIdle="5" 
 maximumPoolSize="100"
 connectionTimeout="300000"
 registerMbeans="true"
 driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
 jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testdb;domain=dev;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;prepareSQL=3"  
 dataSource.implicitCachingEnabled="true"
 dataSource.user=""
 dataSource.password=""  
 connectionTestQuery="Select 1" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that the library is using log4j to log?

Comment: @duffymo the library seems to be using slf4j, so if Vyas uses slf4j over log4j it should be fine afaik.

Comment: I have both sl4j(slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar) and log4j(log4j-1.2.14.jar) libraries available in tomcat lib folder. I am not sure which exactly tomcat use internally.

Comment: If Tomcat uses Log4j (Tomcat uses [JUL by default](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html)), you also need the [slf4j-log4j12](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24644066/3080094) jar-file in the Tomcat lib-folder.

Comment: Thanks vanOekel. You are correct. I forgot to add this jar file earlier. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

1 remove console from 
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
2 and remove additivity line